# What is the correct model/type SSD for an old MacBook Pro 13-inch Early 2011?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hdd, sata

My *uncle* has the following MacBook Pro, it according with *About This Mac*

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)
- Processor 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
- Memory 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- Graphics Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB
- HD - 320GB - based on HDD

Furthermore, in the back of the laptop appears `Model No:A1278`. So far, it works in peace but is very slow. In this point is not possible do an upgrade of the macOS itself. Currently it has `OS X Yosemite`.

Anyway - he is looking for to upgrade the hardware to try upgrade the OS itself (*first, about the RAM,it is going to be upgraded from 4GB to 16GB*).

About the HD, I suggested to buy a new HD of 1TB but being SSD.

What is the correct model for this Mac? I want buy one based of WD (Western Digital) - I want from that company because for other laptop I bought:

- WD Blue SA510 SATA SSD
- 1TB of capacity
- WDS100T3B0A-00AXR0 (shown in back of the box package)

So far it is fast as expected. It is:

- [Western Digital 1TB WD Blue SA510 SATA Internal Solid State Drive SSD - SATA III 6 Gb/s, 2.5"/7mm, Up to 560 MB/s - WDS100T3B0A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09ZYQ84CM)

But because this laptop is old, I am sure not sure about what is the correct model for this Mac.

Please confirm if this model is valid, if not, please share an URL of the recommended product.
My uncle should buy this HD in USA.

Thanks for your understanding.

**Extra Question**

- If this MacOS is upgraded to 16GB and 1TB SSD, until what version would be upgraded the OS itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard drive can be upgraded to any 2.5" SATA SSD you wish, as they are standard. Since the SSD will be far faster than any spinning hard drive, there is no need to purchase a premium, very fast SSD. My personal experience with this exact laptop suggests that the improvement is immediately noticeable and extends the usability of the laptop immediately.

The laptop itself can only run High Sierra 10.13.6 as the 'latest' MacOS, as later MacOS are not supported on this laptop. (newer Macs are moving to MacOS 14 at time of writing)

I will suggest that this model is well outside of the supported hardware, and it is beginning to have challenges with digital certificates, websites and even wifi, due to newer standards.

Many websites that use HTTPS rely on current digital certificates that are part of the browser. When these expire, often an update to the browser is sent to provide the new certificates. But without updates, these certificates no longer function and you will find websites that will no longer work, as they no longer allow HTTP, only HTTPS.

Comment: What is MacOS 17? I thought macOS 14 (Sonoma) was the [latest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Timeline_of_releases)?

Comment: There are web browsers whose current releases are compatible with High Sierra. For example, there is [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-supported-operating-systems) and [Opera](https://www.opera.com/download/requirements). However, I imagine soon those two will join [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/117.0.1/system-requirements/), [Brave](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021357112-What-are-the-system-requirements-to-install-Brave-) and [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7100626?hl=en), which require at least Catalina.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, about the web browsers, in other MacBook Pro with `El Capitan` Opera does not open many pages due something about `https` or `ssl` .... and of course it can't be upgraded anymore ... but this laptop is going to work with Linux with a new SSD... Now my uncle must decide the OS problem/situation.

Comment: thanks @DavidAnderson have iOS on the brain. corrected to MacOS 14